# Can one know if a sound instance is currently playing in XNA SoundEffects?

Tags: audio, xna, xna-4.0, soundeffect, soundeffectinstance

Basically, I want to obtain the state of a given instance of SoundEffects in XNA 4.0. Is there a way to know whether a sound is currently playing or stopped?

Comment: If there is no built in method you can simply use a boolean check that you created yourself.

Comment: But with such flag I could only know if the sound was started (played) but not when it has stopped (ended after the duration of the sound)...

Comment: do you know the duration of the sound file too ? simply set the start time and check if time passed is > than the duration of the file.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: Well there might be a built in function that does the job for you so lets wait for other answers.

Comment: Sure, let's wait. However, there are no build-in functions for that (I checked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you need to use `SoundEffectInstance`. You can create it using `SoundEffect.CreateInstance` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.createinstance.aspx). Remember that the `SoundEffectInstance` is created as stopped, initially.

That class has the `SoundEffectInstance.State` property that allows you to get the current state of the sound effect: playing, paused, or stopped.
Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.state.aspx).

Comment: Yes, "if (instance.State == SoundState.Playing)" works nicely.